# c alarm() and pause() causing pause forever

Tags: c

In the following program, pause is interrupted once, but then pause never returns. I have set alarm to interrupt pause, so i am confused why pause never returns?

```
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void sig_alrm(int);
static jmp_buf env_alrm;


int main(int arc, char **argv)
{

    int x;
    x = setjmp(env_alrm);
    printf("setjmp was created with return value: %d\n", x);

    if(signal(SIGALRM, sig_alrm) == SIG_ERR)
    {
            printf("Error settting SIGALRM\n");
            exit(1);
    }


    if((x!= 0) && (x!=1))
    {

            printf("Error setting setjmp\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    printf("Line next to setjmp\n");
    x = alarm(2);
    printf("Alarm set for 2 seconds, remaning secs from previous alarm: %d\n");
    pause();
    printf("Line next to pause()\n");
    alarm(0);
    return 0;
}

static void sig_alrm(int signo)
{
    longjmp(env_alrm, 1);
}
```

Here is the output and the last line shows where the application pauses

```
setjmp was created with return value: 0
Line next to setjmp
Alarm set for 2 seconds, remaining secs from previous alarm: 0
setjmp was created with return value: 1
Line next to setjmp
Alarm set for 2 seconds, remaining secs from previous alarm: 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()` instead, to save and restore the signal masks, which are not saved by default in Linux, to clear any pending signals, from man [setjmp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setjmp):

> POSIX  does not specify whether setjmp() will save the signal mask. In System V it will not.By default, Linux/glibc follows the System V behavior. **If you want to portably save and restore signal masks, use sigsetjmp()
>   and siglongjmp()**.

Note: I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but your code looks like it's supposed to run in an infinite loop, calling `longjmp()` restores execution as if it had just returned  from `setjmp()` and it goes on forever.

Comment: I am simply trying to understand why does program never returns as shown in my output after second call to alarm?

Comment: Signal handlers block more signals. Since you never exit the signal handler (by the normal means) you never get a second signal. `siglongjump` will reenable signals again.

Comment: @ams +1 for explaining blocking of signals in case of longjmp()

Comment: @ams maybe, but say you were able to somehow clear (unblock) the signal, to allow subsequent signals, that won't matter if the signal mask is not restored, right ?

Comment: @mux as you can see, when longjmp returns, i re-establish signalhandler for SIGALRM.

Comment: @Jimm yes that explains it, to get around that you have to restore the signal masks, using `sigsetjmp()` and `siglongjmp()` which I think, clears the pending signals.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://linux.die.net/man/2/pause :

> pause() only returns when a signal was caught and the **signal-catching
>   function returned**.

In your case it never returns, it does the `longjmp` out.

Comment: ok, in that case, it should keep doing longjmp every 2 seconds, because SIGALRM would fire every 2 seconds..but this is not the observed behavior. The application simply does nothing after the first  longjmp

Comment: @Jimm, Signals are blocked, when jumping to signal handler, which you have never returned from. You can get expected behavior by getting signal mask before `setjmp` and restoring afterwards. Safe way to do this is using `sigsetjmp`.